# Javascript Objects Arrow-function and this

Tags: javascript, this, arrow-functions

Learning JS and behaviour of `this` keyword ... want to understand whats happening below

Declared a Class ( point2 )

```js
class point2 {
    constructor(x,y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y=y;
    }
    dump() {
        (print = () => {
            console.log(this.x + " " + this.y);
        }).call(this);
    }
}

p1 = new point2(1,2);
p1.dump(); // prints undefined
```

But not sure why `p1.dump()` call is printing undefined

was thinking `p1.dump()` would setup this to point2 object, and then `print arrow` function would inherit `this` ( which would be point2 object) and hence expected it to print `1 2`

Comment: As far as I can recall, arrow functions are bound to their lexical context and that cannot be changed, even with `.call`, `.apply`, `.bind`, etc. Even with that in mind, it's entirely unclear what you're trying to do with `.call()`

Comment: `p1.dump()` is returning `undefined` because it doesn't `return` anything

Comment: You were evaluating `p1.dump()` in a REPL. The return value of `p1.dump()` is `undefined` because there's no `return` statement. The log works just fine and prints `1 2` as expected.

Comment: When you call `p1.dump()` it prints "1 2" in the console. The function has no return statement and `console.log(...)` doesn't return anything, so the function returns `undefined` by default.

Comment: @RobG tried on chrome dev tools console `p2 = new point2(3,4);p2.dump()` and still observe `undefined`

Comment: @Shashi—because, as everyone keeps telling you, the method doesn't return anything at all, so by default the call returns *undefined* as if you'd written `console.log((()=>{})())`.

Comment: got that thanks @RobG , my bad had a filter on in the console :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p1.dump()` returns `undefined` because you don't return anything.

```js
class point2 {
    constructor(x,y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y=y;
    }
    dump() {
        (print = () => {
            console.log(this.x + " " + this.y);
        }).call(this);

        return true; // return something here and the console.log will have result
    }
}

p1 = new point2(1,2);
p1.dump(); // undefined
```

[image: Try it on devtool]

`undefined` is what method returns. So because the method does not have `return` keyword so it will return `undefined`. `1 2` is logged out as expected.

Comment: @Shashi, it prints `1 2`, doesn't it?

Comment: thanks @Tan Dat , but not sure why on Chrome DevTools Console `p2=new point2(3,4);p2.dump();`  print undefined ?

Comment: @Shashi: `undefined` is what method returns

Comment: thanks @Tan Dat , my bad had some filters on in console ... but thanks for enlightening me :)